# Create form label from model and Questions from another model in django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two model:

```
class Questions(models.Model):
  question = models.TextField(verbose_name='Question')
  def get_answers(self):
      query = self.answers.select_related()
      for q in query:
          return q

  def __unicode__(self):
      return u'%s'%(self.question)

class Answers(models.Model):
   answers = models.CharField(verbose_name='answer')
   question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, related_name="answers")

   def __unicode__(self):
       return u'%s'%(self.answers)
```

I want to create a form that forms label created from Question and answers from Answers. I have created a form like this:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self,questions, *args, **kwargs):
        self.questions = questions
        for question in questions:
            field_name = "question_%d" % question.pk
            choices = []
            for answer in question.answers.all():
                choices.append((answer.pk,answer.answers))

            field = forms.ChoiceField(label=question.question, required=True,
                                  choices=choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
        return super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT:

```
def my_view(request):
    questions = Questions.objects.filter(......)
    form = QuestionForm(questions)
    return render_to_response('my_view.html',
                          {
                            'form':form
                          },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But with above view, there is not any form in template. What is wrong in my `QuestionForm` from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "there is not any form in template" mean? Post your view code.

Comment: Do you mean literally that `form` is undefined in the template? Maybe you should post your template as well ;).

Comment: The problem is that there's nothing inherently wrong with your `QuestionForm`. Having the template code might shed light on some other issue that might be in play. However, you side-stepped the question. Is `form` literally undefined in the template? Additionally, you're not getting any errors are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your class for this, your form will works

```
 class QuestionForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self,questions, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.questions = questions
        for question in questions:
            field_name = "question_%d" % question.pk
            choices = []
            for answer in question.answers.all():
                choices.append((answer.pk,answer.answers))

            self.fields[fields_name] = forms.ChoiceField(label=question.question, required=True,
                              choices=choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

Comment: +1 Nice catch. I didn't even notice that he wasn't ever actually adding the field to `self.fields`

Comment: we cant because `'QuestionForm' object has no attribute 'fields'`

Comment: Please change "your class" for "my class". The call to super should be the first